# How do I call a variable in a class

Tags: php, class, variables

I'm a newbie trying to design an application which calculate scores of students. I'm trying to simplify my work with OOP and I keep having errors here. This is the class I made:

```
class fun {
var $totalscore;
public function score($assignment,$cat,$exam){

      return $totalscore = $assignment+$cat+$exam;

        if($totalscore <=100 && $totalscore >=70){
            return $grade = "A";
        }
        elseif($totalscore <=69 && $totalscore>=60){
            return $grade = "B";
        }
        elseif($totalscore <=59 && $totalscore>=50){
            return $grade = "C";
        }
        elseif($totalscore <=35 && $totalscore>=49){
            return $grade = "D";
        }
        elseif($totalscore <=40 && $totalscore>=34){
            return $grade = "E";
        }
        elseif($totalscore <=39 && $totalscore>=0){
        return $grade = "F";


 }
 }
 }
```

now im trying to call the variables i mean $totalscore and $grade in my other php below

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $gnsa = $_POST['gnsa'];
    $gnst =$_POST['gnst'];
    $gnse =$_POST['gnse'];
    $agidi =$_POST['matric'];

   include ("class.php");
   $fun = new fun;
   $fun-> score($gnsa,$gnst,$gnse);
   if($totalscore > 100){
    echo "invalid score";
   }
   }
```

Comment: What are the errors you are receiving?

Comment: Pick a PHP/Programming book and learn more - that would better help you

Comment: Take a step back and just think about how functions work. You cannot access local variables of a function from the calling code. Also, when you have a `return` statement inside a function, following statements won't be executed. You should read one or the other tutorial first.

Comment: if it is public: $fun->totalscore, $THE_CLASS_INSTANCE->VARNAME, inside the class you use $this->VARNAME in a method

Comment: Also, your if blocks don't make sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class fun
{
    // notice these 2 variables... they will be available to you after you
    // have created an instance of the class (with $fun = new fun())
    public $totalscore;
    public $grade;

    public function score($assignment, $cat, $exam)
    {
        $this->totalscore = $assignment + $cat + $exam;

        if ($this->totalscore >= 70) {
            $this->grade = "A";
        }
        else if ($this->totalscore <= 69 && $this->totalscore >= 60) {
            $this->grade = "B";
        }
        else if ($this->totalscore <= 59 && $this->totalscore >= 50) {
            $this->grade = "C";
        }

        else if ($this->totalscore <= 35 && $this->totalscore >= 49) {
            $this->grade = "D";
        }

        // there is probably something wrong here... this number (40) shouldn't
        // be higher than the last one (35)
        else if ($this->totalscore <= 40 && $this->totalscore >= 34) {
            $this->grade = "E";
        }
        else {
            $this->grade = "F";
        }
    }
}
```

Now, after you do `$fun->score($gnsa,$gnst,$gnse);`, you will be able to access the total score and grade with `$fun->totalscore` and `$fun->grade` respectively.

Comment: Thanks alot, ive got the code working. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

When using your class you are correctly calling the method like this:

```
$fun->score($gnsa,$gnst,$gnse);
```

Variables (usually called members or attributes) of a class are just called similarly (provided they are public):

```
if($fun->totalscore > 100){
    echo "invalid score";
}
```